# Tools required for windows mobile 8.1 app development

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

I am having a nokia lumia 720 ,for which half of the screen touch is not working.So I decided to make a app which clicks internally (like a mouse pointer for screen) as changing the display at my place is difficult(not having enough money) I am using windows phone 8.1,visual studio 2012 and my desktop OS is windows 8 32 bit(not activated,trail version) can any body help me what are the tools required for developing windows phone app at my case.I have searched MSDN where I didn't get much help.

Comment: could you please provide the reason for down vote..

Answer (score 0):

You need to [register as an app developer](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/join).
Then [download the tools](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk).

I'm not 100% sure, but I think Visual Studio 2013 may be required for Windows Phone 8.1 app development. You should be able to use the free Express edition.